# GIT repo with submodule that can point to two different repositories

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules

We have a repo that has a few submodules. One of the submodule directories is an API.  Depending on the branch of the main repo, the API subdirectory either points to API_V1 repo or API_V2 repo.  If I clone the main repo, and am on develop,  it points to API_V2 when I submodule init/update.  But if I switch to an very old branch instead of develop, and do a submodule update or init/update git is unable to find the correct commit in the API submodule because it's still using API_V2.  Is it possible to get git to change to the correct repo in the API submodule.  Our devops did this to avoid having to rename the API subdir to API_V1 and API_V2, which would have needed many script changes.
Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this in git or basing it on branches. Consider using environment variables instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to use `git submodule update` after switching branches.

Comment: `git submodule sync` after switching branches and then `git submodule update`

Comment: @phd Will `git submodule sync` actually remove the other submodule repo/folder before adding the desired one?

Comment: @joanis No. It syncs URLs from `.gitmodules` (which was checked out from an old commit) to `.git/config`.

Comment: @phd that's the answer, might as well give it as one. The only thing even a little bit wrong with putting all the histories you've found useful to have in a repo in that repo is if they've got conflicting annotated tags, but submodules don't care about that either.

Comment: @jthill An answer requires much more elaboration. See below.

Comment: Submodules are a poor replacement for dependency management. Package the APIs using your language's packaging system and depend on them as normal. You don't need to formally release them, most dependency managers can pull directly from a git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After switching branches with `git checkout` or `git switch` in the superproject (parent repository) an old `.gitmodules` is checked out. If the file has different URLs for the submodules the URLs should be updated in `.git/config` because Git doesn't use URLs from `.gitmodules` directly, it only uses `.git/config`. The command to update the URLs is `git submdule sync` (add `--recursive` if you have a tree of submodules). After that `git submodule update --init` should update submodules to the respective commits stored in the superproject.

You can automate the process with [`post-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout). Put this

```bash
#!/bin/sh
new_branch="$3"

if [ "$new_branch" = 1 ]; then
    git submodule sync --recursive
    git submodule update --init --recursive
fi

exit 0
```

in `.git/hooks/post-checkout`, make the file executable by running `chmod a+x .git/hooks/post-checkout`